# Dynamic multiple instances of tinymce editor in template driven nested form

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor for my angular 12 project

1)I can create multiple instances of tinymce editor, if I use it directly inside the template driven form, provided 'id' is unique

```
   <editor [apiKey]="tinymceAPIKey" id="myidone" name="myidone" 
   [(ngModel)]="descriptionone" [init]="tinyMCEEditorService.tinymceInitProp">

    <editor [apiKey]="tinymceAPIKey" id="myidtwo" name="myidtwo" 
    [(ngModel)]="descriptiontwo" [init]="tinyMCEEditorService.tinymceInitProp">
```

2. If I use it inside a nested form (template driven), which I can access using ngForm directive (<form #form="ngForm">), I can still create multiple instances of tinymce editor by passing ids ("myidone" and "myidtwo") as input value.

Inside parent:

```
   <app-tinymce [id]="myidone" ..></app-tinymce>
   <app-tinymce [id]="myidtwo" ..></app-tinymce>
```

Nested tinymce component/template

```
    @Input() editorid: string;
    ... 

        <editor [apiKey]="tinymceAPIKey" [id]="editorid" name="description" 
 [(ngModel)]="description" [init]="tinyMCEEditorService.tinymceInitProp">
```

3. Problem is how to get separate values for id "myidone" and "myidtwo"? When there was only one instance, I was able to access using this.form.value.<name>. I tried to pass "name" attribute dynamically, but did not work. It gives me error (All combinations)

   ```
   name="{{editorid}}" OR     
   [name]="editorid" OR 
   [attr.name]="editorid" OR 
   attr.name="{{editorid}}"


    Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute 
    must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
   ```
4. I can remove "name" attribute by declaring as 'standalone', but in that case how can I access nested form values by Id (template driven)?
5. Any other alternative solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it correctly, but do you want to use multiple tinyEditors in a reactive form?

I have added an implementation of same on stackblitz.

- Code: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ejynrv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
- Output: [here](https://angular-ivy-ejynrv.stackblitz.io)

Please have a look.

Comment: Main issue I am facing is getting value from nested form (template driven) using id.